# PHP / RSS Feed Dating Setup

Tags: php, rss

I have an RSS feed generated from a custom blog I have designed; however, one of my posts keeps showing up on my RSS Reader daily.  I finally checked the date and saw it was showing up   daily, but from the year 2000.  Google Reader shows the date as when the post is updated daily but looking at the XML code, that is where it shows 2000.  All the other posts are shown as 1969.

Here is how I have my php code setup:

```
$rssfeed.='<pubDate>'.date("D, d M Y H:i:s O",strtotime($date)).'</pubDate>';
```

Is this the correct way?

EDIT:  I am possibly an idiot -- I don't show $date as a variable in my code -- out of curiosity, what SHOULD be there?

Comment: Unrelated but PHP and RSS feeds should definitely been dating, they've been eyeing each other for years, it's time they start going out.

Comment: you can use date('r') or  date('r', strtotime($date))
If posts show 1969 then $date may not be in the correct format and strtotime failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, here is complete code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    extract($row);
    $rssfeed.='<item>';
    $rssfeed.='<title>'.$title.'</title>';
    $rssfeed.='<description>'.validate($news).'</description>';
    $rssfeed.='<pubDate>'.date('r',$date).'</pubDate>';
    $rssfeed.='</item>';
}
```

Where it says `$date` in the second to last line, I had it wrapped in `strtotime` for some reason.  I removed that, and all is well!

Answer (score 2):

> **pubDate** The publication date for the content in the channel. For example, the New York Times publishes on a daily basis, the publication date flips once every 24 hours. That's when the pubDate of the channel changes. All date-times in RSS conform to the Date and Time Specification of **RFC 822**, with the exception that the year may be expressed with two characters or four characters (four preferred).  *Sat, 07 Sep 2002 00:00:01 GMT*

See: http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html

```
$fromStringDate = strtotime($date);
if (!$fromStringDate) throw new Exception(sprintf('Date-Failure in "%s"', $date));
$rfc822Date = date("r", $fromStringDate);
$rssfeed .= sprintf('<pubDate>%s</pubDate>', $rfc822Date);
```

See also: http://php.net/date